# POST Request using ASP.NET WEB API and HttpCLient Giving Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do a Post Request with ASP.net , I have my web api running , and i have my app that i pass my methods to call the api, Im trying to do a POST request using Http Client and here is my Controller

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        var user = new LutUsers();
        var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/user/findusers", stringContent);

        Response.Write(response);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Storing the response details recieved from web api   

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Connection Made successfully!');</script>")   
        }
        return View();
    }
```

the **Response.write(respone)**

give me this error : **StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent**

can somebody please help me find what i'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class?force_isolation=true

Comment: what line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying do retrieve some informations about users and I suppose the endpoint that you are using for this not allow a request with http verb POST try use a GET request instead.